# Split comma from a LongArrayList

Tags: java, list, arraylist, containers

I 've an Long ArrayList and it contains

```
[1982,1984,1986]
```

How can I separate the comma's and get the years as a String? Like this:

> 1982
>   1984
>   1986

This is my code so far:

```
private String yearValue(MyProject myProjects){
    List<Long> myList = new ArrayList<>();

    List<MyValues> values = myProject.getProjects().getYearvalues();

    String year = "";

    for (MyValue value : values){
        Long key = (long)value.getYearvalues();
        if(!myList.contains(key)){
            myList.add(key);
        }
        year = myList.toString();
    }
    return year;
}
```

Comment: You can start by writing a code.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: @MS_SP. That's not string, but a `List`.

Comment: Yes I 've tried something like convert the list toString so:
List<long> myList = new ArrayList<>();
String temp = "";
temp = myList.toString();

then try to loop through the string  but I don't get the proper result.

Comment: Maybe a question for the Meta: if there is no code, but it is 99.999% clear what and how the OP did, and how that failed, does it still count as "showing no efforts"? However, it would certainly help the question to get answered to include the actual code...

Answer (score 2):

Even without a line of code, it is obvious that you use `toString()` on the list, like this:

```
System.out.println(myList.toString());
```

Don't use `toString()` of the ArrayList class for this purpose. Use proper formatting:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for(Long l:myList) {
    if(sb.length()>0) {
        sb.append(' '); // this is the separator between the items. '\n' will result in line breaks
    }
    sb.append(l);
}
String myString=sb.toString();
```

This code concatenates the Long elements in the array to one string, separated by single spaces. Is it not a one liner? No it is not. It is verbose. And instantly readable.

**UPDATE** to get the years in separate lines, just swap the `' '` to `'\n'`.

**Why did I downvote Ruchira?** Does his solution return incorrect results? No, it returns exactly the same. Why am I so much of a jock then?

- Most importantly: his solution is *definitely* not easy to read. Regex is a very powerful tool, but it is challenging to read and comprehend a regexp, even this simple, compared to proper code. Always be kind to your colleagues and write readable code. Also, if I need to build a house, I don't want to build 2 houses, and demolish one to get the result...
- Medium importantly: uses List.toString(). This ties the code to exact behavior of *one implementation*. Very bad practice in the long term.

**TL;DR** This is basically only for my own amusement here:

- **Least** importantly (remember Knuth!): His solution is slow. Ok, not for 4 long instances, but serializing and applying a regexp costs more. Not very significant (Full SSCCE at end of post.).

All runs have 1000000 conversions of previously generated random Longs in the range `[0;9999]`, with a `System.gc()` suggestion and a `Thread.sleep(1000)` between each batch, executed with `-Xmx4096m -Xms4096m` to be sure. The first run should not be taken into count of course.

```
Method       STRING_BUILDER:    78 ms Method         REGEX_STRING:   312 ms Method           REGEX_LONG:   265 ms Method REGEX_STRING_PRECOMP:   249 ms 
Method       STRING_BUILDER:    47 ms Method         REGEX_STRING:   234 ms Method           REGEX_LONG:   202 ms Method REGEX_STRING_PRECOMP:   234 ms 
Method       STRING_BUILDER:    46 ms Method         REGEX_STRING:   234 ms Method           REGEX_LONG:   219 ms Method REGEX_STRING_PRECOMP:   218 ms 
Method       STRING_BUILDER:    47 ms Method         REGEX_STRING:   219 ms Method           REGEX_LONG:   187 ms Method REGEX_STRING_PRECOMP:   203 ms 
Method       STRING_BUILDER:    47 ms Method         REGEX_STRING:   218 ms Method           REGEX_LONG:   187 ms Method REGEX_STRING_PRECOMP:   172 ms
```

Code, for those bored enough:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


public class A {
  private static final String REGEX_PATTERN_STRING = "\\[|\\]|\\,";

  private static final int ITERATIONS = 1000000;

  private static final Pattern PRECOMPILED_PATTERN = Pattern.compile(REGEX_PATTERN_STRING);
  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    //first warmup, then real tests
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++) {
      List<Long> randomLongs = getRandomLongs(ITERATIONS, 9999);
      List<String> randomLongsInStrings = convertToStringList(randomLongs);

      StringBuilder resultLine = new StringBuilder();
      List<String> returns = new ArrayList<String>(Methods.values().length);

      for(Methods m : Methods.values()) {
        long time=System.currentTimeMillis();
        returns.add(m.convert(randomLongs, randomLongsInStrings));
        time=System.currentTimeMillis()-time;
        resultLine.append(String.format("Method %20s: %5d ms ", m.name(), time));
      }

      //check to be the same
      for(int returnCheck=1;returnCheck<returns.size();returnCheck++) {
        if(!returns.get(returnCheck-1).equals(returns.get(returnCheck))) {
          throw new IllegalStateException("Error, mismatch!");
        }
      }

      System.out.println(resultLine.toString());

      System.gc(); // suggest for GC to happen
      Thread.sleep(1000); // allow JVM to do GC if it needs to
    }

  }


  private static List<Long> getRandomLongs(int howMany, int magnitude) {
    List<Long> longList = new ArrayList<Long>();
    for(int i=0;i<howMany;i++) {
      longList.add(Math.round(Math.random()*magnitude));
    }
    return longList;
  }

  private static <T> List<String> convertToStringList(List<T> inputList) {
    List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(T inputElement:inputList) {
      stringList.add(inputElement.toString());
    }
    return stringList;
  }

  private enum Methods {

    STRING_BUILDER {
      @Override
      public String convert(List<Long> longList, List<String> stringList) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for(Long l:longList) {
            if(sb.length()>0) {
                sb.append(' ');
            }
            sb.append(l);
        }
        return sb.toString();
      }

    },
    REGEX_STRING{

      @Override
      public String convert(List<Long> longList, List<String> stringList) {
        return longList.toString().replaceAll(REGEX_PATTERN_STRING,"");
      }

    },
    REGEX_LONG{

      @Override
      public String convert(List<Long> longList, List<String> stringList) {
        return stringList.toString().replaceAll(REGEX_PATTERN_STRING,"");
      }

    },
    REGEX_STRING_PRECOMP {

      @Override
      public String convert(List<Long> longList, List<String> stringList) {
        return PRECOMPILED_PATTERN.matcher(stringList.toString()).replaceAll("");
      }

    };

    public abstract String convert(List<Long> longList, List<String> stringList);

  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you info:)
I 'm going to try it and 'll Let you know

Comment: I would be grateful for the downvoter to teach me about my mistakes: please share why.

Comment: Instead of checking the length in each iteration you can simply test at the end for `if (sb.length() > 1) sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length()-1)`. This will always remove the last comma if it is there. Nice explanation, though :)

Comment: @allprog or I could use a boolean named isFirst - would be quicker than my original one. Sometimes building takes quite a lot - and I get no replies from prototype manufacturers, so I can afford writing a benchmark suite in a couple of build time coffee breaks...

Comment: sure, the difference may be serveral hundred CPU cycles at >2GHz... negligible :)